# Pass value to Apache Httpclient Response Handler

Tags: response, apache-httpclient-4.x, json-deserialization

Hi I am using apache http client and i was wondering of it is possible top have a generic response hande. I want a generic function but not a generic class. I dont want to have to create a new response handler per request.

I only know the return object at runtime hence my need to inform handleResponse() of which object to deserialize json response into.
I could return a string and deserialize afterwards but that will just give me performace overhead.
When i try to return the stream reader, the stream is closed by the time the function returns.
Is there a way to pass a parameter to the handleResponse() function?

Answer (score 0):

`ResponseHandler` parameter signature is given and cannot be changed.

But there is nothing stopping you from using a custom function, is there?

```
static class HttpRequestExecutor implements Closeable  {

    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpRequestExecutor(final CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public <P, T> T execute(final HttpHost target,
                            final HttpRequest request,
                            final HttpContext context,
                            final P parameter,
                            final BiFunction<HttpResponse, P, T> handler) throws IOException  {
        try (final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, request, context)) {
            final T result = handler.apply(response, parameter);
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final HttpRequestExecutor executor = new HttpRequestExecutor(HttpClients.createSystem());

    final HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("httpbin.org");
    final HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get("/").build();
    final HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    executor.execute(httpHost, request, context, Void.TYPE, (httpResponse, voidClass) -> null);
}
```

Comment: why do we need to do `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());` after handler.apply? isn't the entity already consumed by BiFunction?

Comment: @eatSleepCode it is just a safe-guard in case the handler does not fully consume the message content

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not needed but did something recently... I'm using GSON but you can change to whatever you want.. Some code with explanation follows. Handle the static methods/exceptions etc.

```
private static void executeCall() throws APIException {
    // Your REQUEST DTO.. example...
    ExampleRequestDto request = new ExampleRequestDto("value", "value");
    // Instantiate once as a static variable ?!?
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Object to json string
    String jsonRequest = gson.toJson(request);
    // Create http post object, or get.
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("your.endpoint.url");  
    // Add request dto to body...if not needed dont add.
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonRequest, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    // The response/your object dto to transform the json response
    ExampleResponseDto response = getApiResponse(httpPost, ExampleResponseDto.class);
}


// Don't throw generic exception... Handle specific ones that you need
public static <T> T getApiResponse(HttpUriRequest request, Class<T> responseDtoClass) throws Exception {
    // I'm creating a default client... Do your thing.
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<T>() {
            @Override
            public T handleResponse(final HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                // Handle statuscode and null value?!?
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                try (InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    // Instantiate once as a static variable ?!?
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    // Return object
                    return gson.fromJson(reader, responseDtoClass);
                }
            }
        };
        return httpclient.execute(request, responseHandler);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException | JsonSyntaxException | JsonIOException e) {
        // Don't throw generic exception... Handle specific ones that you need
        throw new Exception("Connection error for request");
    }
}
```